# Javascript unique array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I have an array like this:

```
var data = [
            { Group: 'A', Name: 'SD' },
            { Group: 'B', Name: 'FI' },
            { Group: 'A', Name: 'MM' },            
            { Group: 'B', Name: 'CO' }
           ];
```

I want to get only the unique Group values in an array like:

```
var unique = ['A','B'];
```

I looked at some of the examples on SO but I don't understand them. Can anyone tell me how I should do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = [
             { Group: 'A', Name: 'SD' },
             { Group: 'B', Name: 'FI' },
             { Group: 'A', Name: 'MM' },            
             { Group: 'B', Name: 'CO' }
           ];

var set = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    set[data[i].Group] = 1;

var arr = [];
for(var key in set)
    arr.push(key);

alert(arr);
```

Comment: Replace that loop with `arr = Object.keys(set)`

Comment: FYI, `Object.keys` is new in ECMAScript 5, so it may not be available in all browsers ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys))

Comment: @PetarIvanov This works great in IE9. As per Cheran's FYI, this will not work in IE < 9. Any suggestion on how I should this without Object.keys() ?

Comment: @user686924: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatiblity

Comment: @user686924: I reverted back to my original solution, which doesn't use `Object.keys`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6/ES2015 or later you can do it this way:

```
var unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.Group))];
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/vlad-bezden/pen/OMEXJz?editors=0012) is an example on how to do it.